# Share PartialView between projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am developing 2 MVC5 websites. They run seperately, but actually related to each other (1 Admin site, and 1 User site). In both site, I have to render a graphical board using HTML table. I am using PartialView with a Model to render it.

Currently, this is my solution structure:

- Project.Common (A class library project, contain the model)
- Project.Admin (MVC5 project for the Admin site), refering to Project.Common.
- Project.User (MVC5 project for User site), refering to Project.Common.

To render the graphical board, I will use `BoardData` class from Project.Common, which is ok. But with current solution structure, I have to create 2 PartialView in each MVC5 project, which may be hard to maintain later.

Please suggest a good solution for reusing the PartialView. I already know I can write Helper, but that way, I have to write HTML code inside C# code, which is not very good. Is there any way to do this within Razor View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the options you can use is add a link to a file. In this case keep your Partial view in just single project and in second project use `Add -> Existing Item`, select your partial view from the first project and click on a small down arrow next to the `Add` button and choose `Add as Link`. More info can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx), see section Add an existing item as a link.

In this case you will have a partial view only in one project and any changes to it will automatically be applied to other project as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should embed your views into the Project.Common dll, a detailed description can be found on https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f28290ce-d987-4f91-b034-707031e10ce6